# CakePHP: How to update model data from a model method?

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to stick with the "Fat Model" approach in programming my CakePHP app and am currently stumped in my attempts to get a function working in one of my models.  Here's a slightly simplified version of my code.

See the part where it says "This is where the trouble starts" and a bunch of lines are commented out.  I can't figure out how to save the headers info to the model instance, because I'm using "findByID" which returns an array instead of an object.

I found another thread ([CakePHP 2.0 Object not Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7946480/cakephp-2-0-object-not-array)) discussing the array vs. object issue.  It seems that's part of the design of Cake 2.X, though I don't really understand why.  Anyway I don't want a workaround as is suggested in that other thread, but rather I want to understand how to do this correctly:

```
// app/Model/Datareportdoc.php
App::uses('AppModel', 'Model');

class Datareportdoc extends AppModel {  

public function parseData($id) {

    $results = ""; // init
    $filepath = ""; // init

    $reportdoc = $this->findById($id);
    $filepath = $reportdoc['Datareportdoc']['filepath'];
    $headers = array(); // init

    // Parse and save the report data
    if (($handle = fopen($filepath, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        $row = 0;
        while (($datarow = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $num = count($datarow);
            // If it's a header row, create the headers array
            if ($row == 0) {
                $results .= "HEADER ROW\n";
                $dataheaders = implode(",", $datarow);
                // *** THIS IS WHERE THE TROUBLE STARTS ***
                //$this->Datareportdoc->id = $id; // NO: "Indirect modification of overloaded property"
                //$this->Datareportdoc->set('dataheaders', $dataheaders); // No, because we have an array, not an object :-(
                //$this->Datareportdoc->dataheaders = $dataheaders;
                //$this->Datareportdoc->save(); // NO: Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object
// Also tried this, which also doesn't work
                //$reportdoc['Datareportdoc']['dataheaders'] = $dataheaders;
                //$reportdoc->save();
                $results .= "Datareportdoc dataheaders: ".$dataheaders."\n";
            } else {
                $data = array();
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($headers as $header) {
                    $data[$header] = $datarow[$i];
                    $i++;
                }
                $results .= "Got data for insert:\n".print_r($data, true)."\n\n\n";
                // @TODO: Insert the data...
            }
            $row++;
        }
        fclose($handle);
    } else {
        $results .= "fopen failed :-(<br />\n";
        //echo "fopen failed :-(<br />\n";
        //exit();
    }
    return $results;
}

}
```

Comment: P.S. Yes, I have looked in the CakePHP documentation and read about Saving Data ([link](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/saving-your-data.html)), but the examples given there only seem to work in Controller methods... Am I missing something really basic and obvious?

Answer (score 0):

So give this a shot:

Instead of this:

```
//$this->Datareportdoc->id = $id;
//$this->Datareportdoc->set('dataheaders', $dataheaders); // No, because we have an array, not an object :-(
//$this->Datareportdoc->dataheaders = $dataheaders;
//$this->Datareportdoc->save();
```

Use this:

```
$this->save($dataheaders);
```

It works every time in the model when done this way.

(Background: CakePHP 2.x cookbook talks a 'little' bit about active record .... but it's not really if you're used to other platforms, not in the sense I understand the term anyway. (3.0 is ORM and active record, but not so for 2.x)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer.  It doesn't work, though. Did you mean that I should un-comment one or more of those lines you quoted, or simply replace them with the line of code you suggested?  I tried the latter, and the error is as follows: "Error: Call to a member function save() on a non-object".  Also just writing save($dataheaders) doesn't include enough information to indicate what field that data belongs in, does it?

Comment: Aha! Thanks for putting me on the right track, anyway.  This works: $reportdoc['Datareportdoc']['dataheaders'] = $dataheaders;
$this->save($reportdoc);

Comment: Ok. if that works, then I think what you didn't mention in your post was that your 'dataheaders' is a related model to Datareportdoc? Otherwise I would have pointed you that way. Nevertheless, if the answer helped you, I'd appreciate if you click the 'right answer' checkbox so I get some cred. ;) thanks

Comment: "dataheaders" is not a related model, but rather one attribute of a Datareportdoc.  $reportdoc is an instance of a Datareportdoc (see above:$reportdoc = $this->findById($id);) and I need to save the dataheaders to one column in the datatable corresponding to the Datareportdoc model. I will happily click 'right answer' if you'll modify your answer to reflect this.  If I click the button as is it might confuse other people, since it won't work as written.  Make sense? Thanks! :-)